# Drupal Webform for Activities - CiviCRM Permissions

Tags: webform-civicrm, permissions

I have created a Webform that will be used to create CiviCRM activities for a particular (existing) client. The form is structured in such a way that the client must exist in CiviCRM first, and the person creating the Activity must select the existing client:

[image]

When I'm logged in as an administrator, and submit the form, the data correctly populates the CiviCRM database. However, when I'm logged in as a different role ("Volunteer") with much more limited permissions, the data does not get entered into the database (the webform gets submitted, and I can see the webform results when logged in as an administrator, but the data doesn't get entered into the related CiviCRM fields).

Ideally, the Volunteer role should not be able to create new clients, and should not be able to edit any client data. The Volunteer should ONLY be able to create new activities (Client Needs).

So in the Drupal permissions, I have things like the following turned OFF for the "Volunteer" role:

- CiviCRM: add contacts
- CiviCRM: edit all contacts
- CiviCRM: delete contacts
- CiviCRM: Delete activities
- CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API

... and I have things like the following permissions turned ON for the Volunteer Role:

- CiviCRM: view all contacts
- CiviCRM: view all activities
- CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard
- CiviCRM: add contact notes
- CiviCRM: access AJAX API

Clearly, I'm missing some sort of permission that the volunteer needs in order to create a new activity for a client. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue in your case was that Contact 1 was not set on the form

Comment: Thank you, Pete. For the benefit of others reading this (who don't have admin access to the site in question!), that was exactly the problem. Contact 1 didn't have anything set, and wasn't matched to "Existing Contact".